# Find the rows of data in a database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I need some basic help with my code, I want to fetch the data from the sqlite3 database using with the variable `self.channels_Index`.

I'm using `self.channels_Index` to defined it when I add up the value in each time when I pressing on the down arrow button of the keyboard.

So when I try this:

```
programs = list()

#get the programs list
profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
con = database.connect(profilePath)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel=?', [self.channels_Index])
programs = cur.fetchall()
start_pos = 375    # indent for first program
print program

for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
    program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])
```

I will get the result like this:

```
17:58:26 T:4976  NOTICE: []
```

My database:

```
ABC Family
ABC Family
ABC Family
ABC Family
ABC Family
..etc until to 69 rows
CBS
CBS
CBS
CBS
CBS
..etc until to 69 rows
ESPN
ESPN
ESPN
ESPN
ESPN
..etc until to 69 rows
FOX NEWS
FOX NEWS
FOX NEWS
FOX NEWS
FOX NEWS
FOX NEWS
..etc until to 69 rows
```

What I want to achieve is to find the rows in the database when `self.channels_Index` show as 7 to or whatever it is that I want to multiply it by 69 times then I want to get the 69 rows of data before print a list of data.

Example: When the `self.channels_Index` show as 4, I want to find the rows of `FOX NEWS` in a database to get the whole data in 69 times then print a list of `FOX NEWS` data.

Can you please help me how I can do that when using with `self.channels_Index`?

**EDIT: When I try this:**

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT channel FROM programs;')
channel_list = sorted(row[0] for row in cur.fetchall())
cur.execute('SELECT title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel=?;', channel_list[self.channels_Index])
programs = cur.fetchall()
```

It give me the error: ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.

Comment: Tag the database buddy

Comment: @BhargavRao do you want me to send a link of my database or what?

Comment: oh yeah sorry i got what you mean. i am going to tag it so hopefully the others will help me out.

Comment: ok i have done it so does anyone know how I can find the rows in a database using the value?

Comment: does anyone know?????????

Comment: How would the program know that 4 corresponds to "FOX NEWS"?

Comment: @CL. I have no idea but i'm sure it can be done by finding the rows with the index. I have stored 69 rows for each data so how I can find the rows to fetch the 69 data of `FOX NEWS` using the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `channels_Index` variable to refer to the i<sup>th</sup> channel, sorted alphabetically in ascending order. In a database, there is no guaranteed sort order, so you would have to figure out the name of the i<sup>th</sup> channel first. The pure SQL way would be to use a query that explicitly sorts the data; for example, this query would get you the *third* channel, in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT channel FROM programs ORDER BY channel ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

But you want to be able to browse through different channels, and the `OFFSET` value isn't one you can parameterize in your query. A better solution might be to just get all the channel names first, and sort them in Python:

```
cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT channel FROM programs;')
channel_list = sorted(row[0] for row in cur.fetchall())
```

Now you can refer to the i<sup>th</sup> channel by applying the index to `channel_list` and passing the result to your query:

```
cur.execute('SELECT title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel=?;',
            (channel_list[self.channels_Index],))
```

You don't need to select `channel` since you know its value already. This approach works no matter how many rows there are in your database corresponding to each channel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have tried to use the code you have post but it give me the error: `ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.`, do you know why? I have updated the code in my question on above where you can see that I have edited.